# How to add array values to another array

Tags: laravel

I have two sets of array A and B, array A and B on submission is supposed to enter a database table.

```
A(result)
array:2 [
  0 => 7
  1 => 8
]

B
array:3 [
  "student_test_id" => 8
  "question_id" => 4
  "test_id" => 3
]
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

On submit, i want the values of Array A and B to enter this table like this

```
id| student_test_id | test_id | question_id |result 
1 | 8               | 3       | 4           | 7
2 | 8               | 3       | 4           | 8
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

```
$result = $request->result;
        $array_conv = array(
            "student_test_id"=>$request->student_test_id,
            "question_id"=>$request->question_id,
            "test_id"=>$request->test_id,
        );
        foreach($request->result as $result){
            $test_log = new StudentTestLog();
            $test_log->student_test_id = $array_conv["student_test_id"];
            $test_log->question_id = $array_conv["question_id"];
            $test_log->test_id = $array_conv["test_id"];
            $test_log->result = $result['id'];
            $test_log->save();
            if($test_log->save()){
                return response()->json('Submited', 200);
            }else{
                return response()->json('Error Submitting', 400);
            }
        }
```

Please assist Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning response from foreach except first all other iterations of loop are omitted as `return` ends method execution. You should move return statements outside the loop. Try something like this:

```php
$array_conv = array(
    "student_test_id"=>$request->student_test_id,
    "question_id"=>$request->question_id,
    "test_id"=>$request->test_id,
);

$data_to_persist = [];
foreach($request->result as $result){
    array_push( $data_to_persist, [
        'student_test_id' => $array_conv["student_test_id"],
        'question_id' => $array_conv["question_id"],
        'test_id' => $array_conv["test_id"],
        'result' => $result['id']
    ]);
}

$saved = StudentTestLog::insert( $data_to_persist );
if($saved){
    return response()->json('Submited', 200);
}else{
    return response()->json('Error Submitting', 400);
}
```